# spring MVC rest operation

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

I'm new to web develoment, and the Spring MVC framework in particular. I created a controlle, which accept user requests in JSON format.
the user operations are quite simple, create, update, delete, etc.
in each request, the user sends his password, and after authentication, the operation is handled.
I wanted to know if there's a way in this scenario to create sort of a session with the client, so the client can authenticate only once, and then he'll be able to do various operations, such as updates,queries, etc. when he's done, he'll send a request to close the session, and of course, a timeout will be also initiated once the last operation was done.

The question is, Does Sprin MVC offer this functionality, if not which other frameworks do ?
and above all, is this the proper way to handle user operations in that scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Spring MVC or Spring Core provides such a mechanism. Your best bet would be to try [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) ([reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html)).